# Getting RedisConnectionFailureException

Tags: spring, redis, database-connection

I'm getting the following error when I try to persist something in Redis db from my java spring project.

*Nested in org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool*

Has anyone faced the same error? Any solutions available?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it looks like it cannot connect to the redis server. maybe the url is not right?

Comment: The db is in local only. url is localhost:6379

Comment: can you connect to it when you run `redis-cli`?

Comment: yes. It is connecting via console

Comment: Have you tried setting "usePool" to false on JedisConnectionFactory to  narrow down the problem?

Comment: I had the same problem, maybe you should make sure the redis-server not running in protected mode.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that jedis doesn't connect to localhost, try to connect to real IP.
I've had the same issue and found that though redis-cli connects to localhost and 127.0.0.1, Jedis can connect only to real IP.

Answer (score 1):

The redis server is properly down. just restart redis-server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which was because of the Windows Firewall. Try to disable it or add an inbound rule.